# Geolocate IP address with GeoLite2 database

Tags: geoip

I have a list of IP addresses (IPv4 in the form `122.XXX.XXX.XXX`) which I want to be assigned to a pair of latitude and longitude coordinates; I would be happy also with a approximate location. I downloaded the free GeoLite2 database ([here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/)) but I don't understand how should I proceed, since the IP information in the database is stored as IPv6 (on which I have no experience).

Is there any way to proceed? Should I use drop everything after `::ffff:` and then match the rest of the string with my IPv4? Or should I also drop part of my IPv4, which I want to geolocate?

Answer (score 0):

The GeoLite2 database is in hybrid notation to be forwards compatible. While dropping everything after ::ffff: would work, I would recommend the opposite, convert the IPs you get into hybrid notation and then match. (Just add ::ffff: to the front). This should help if you ever have to start supporting IPv6.